# Where do these "not-found" wagtail errors come from?

Tags: django, error-handling, wagtail

This is a chunk of my HTTP logs from Django v3.2 running wagtail. Looks as though Django is trying to tell me where the missing media is but is not able to. Because this is a thicket page with gallery sub-images of "featured pages" the view source in my browser doesn't reveal the image file attempt, but I am assuming it is the same issue as OP's with misconfigured MEDIA_ROOT. Strangely, not seeing any errors in the page's linked images when I bring the child page up in wagtail admin. Does anyone have an idea why the missing image won't bubble up to the HTTP logs, or what causes the "media/not-found" substitution for the "real" item causing the 404, or how to unravel the error stack? I've found multiple instances of "not-found", but only in the wagtail "site-packages" /lib/python3.8/site-packages/wagtail folder. None of them give me an indication of why the page (or usually image) causing the 404 isn't returned in the HTTP logs but just the "not-found" URL. I could see what the missing image was (part of a block), and it actually wasn't missing, but possibly a cached copy of the page was causing the "not-found" error to be substituted.

````
[25/Aug/2021 20:28:53] "GET /static/wagtailadmin/images/bg-dark-diag.svg HTTP/1.0" 200 700

Not Found: /media/not-found [25/Aug/2021 20:29:18] "GET /media/not-found HTTP/1.0" 404 3252```
````

Answer (score 0):

Whenever an image is included on a template - either using the `{% image %}` tag, or inside a rich text field - Wagtail creates a resized version of the originally uploaded image (which is stored in `media/original_images`) and stores that in `media/images`. The URL of this resized image is then used in the `<img>` tag.

A `/media/not-found` URL indicates that an error occurred while resizing the image, most likely because the source image did not exist on disk, and so the final resized image couldn't be created. (This is most often seen when a Wagtail site has been moved between servers, and the database has been copied across but the images in `media/original_images` haven't.) It's done this way because the alternative would be for the `{% image %}` tag to throw an error, which would break the page completely - it's assumed that a page with one broken image is better than no page at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, makes total sense to be done this way. However, one workaround for me was to completely remove all renditions, using a django admin script called "delete_renditions", then I was able to identify the missing file from "original_images" and replace it. You're correct, this had to do with a "server-to-server" copy, or possibly a "manage.py dumpdata" to create bakerydemo.json where the corresponding rendition was missing from base/media/original_images at "reinstall time."

Comment: I still feel a notation in the logs with the offending rendition would be possible without "breaking the page completely", something a bit more explanatory than the Microsoft-stone-age-era "File not found/53" error from Wagtail (or is it Django?).